# how to check if data is hierarchical in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-structures

prior to display the data I want to check if its hierarchical
first value is by my def not hierarchical

```
// no hierarchy
const hierachNo={
  name: "father",
  children: "no",
};



// hierarchy
const hierachJes ={
  name: "father",
  children: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar"}]
,
};
```

d3 `hierarchy` method automatically sets the first entry as the parent
even if the data is not hierarchical--just two entries without depth.

Is there a way to to check if the data is hierarchical?

Comment: I did not work with d3 hierarchy yet, but if I understand it right, it assumes a structure containing the keys `name` and `children`. So your example would be valid. To check the structure you could use something like this: `var valid = noHirarchy.hasOwnProperty('name') && noHirarchy.hasOwnProperty('children') && Array.isArray(noHirarchy.children)`

Comment: I added an example for clarification

Answer (score 0):

To check the structure you could check for the keys `name` and `children` and if `children` is an array.

```js
// no hierarchy
const hierachNo = {
  name: "father",
  children: "no",
};

// hierarchy
const hierachYes = {
  name: "father",
  children: [{ name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar"}]
};

function isHierachy(item) {
  return item.hasOwnProperty('name') && item.hasOwnProperty('children') && Array.isArray(item.children)
}

console.log(isHierachy(hierachNo));
console.log(isHierachy(hierachYes));
```